# Как сделать, чтобы сборка webpack добавляла все картинки при билде на прод

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, webpack4

Проект на C# раньше фронт собирали на gulp теперь переделали сборку на webpack чтобы подключить vue к проекту. Проблема в том что  при сборке фронта в webpack собираются только те картинки которые прописаны в css, а картинки которые указаны во вьюхах C#  он не собирает в итоге я получаю 404 для картинок которые лежат во вьюхах. Как сделать так чтобы webpack пережимал все картинки и добавлял их при билде на проект ? а не только те картинки чьи пути он видит

```js
const path = require('path');
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const isDevelopment = argv.mode === 'development';
const isProduction = !isDevelopment;
const distPath = path.join(__dirname, '/wwwroot/dist');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const glob = require('glob');
const assets = glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, '/ClientApp/js/**/*.js'));
const layout = glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, '/ClientApp/layout.js'));

const config = {
    entry: {
        assets: assets,
        main: layout,
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: distPath
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: 'html-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }]
        }, 
            {

                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    isDevelopment ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: [
                                isProduction ? require('cssnano') : () => {
                                },
                                require('autoprefixer')({
                                    browsers: ['last 2 versions']
                                })
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }, {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[path]/[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: (file) => {
                            let path = file.split("ClientApp/")[1]; //this will yield assets
                            // let newPath = '../' + path;
                            return path
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    options: {
                        mozjpeg: {
                            progressive: true,
                            quality: 70
                        }
                    }
                },
                ],
            }, {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'
                    }
                },
            }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].min.css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].css'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './ClientApp/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: false,
                    ecma: 6,
                    mangle: false
                },
            }),
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: distPath,
        port: 9000,
        compress: true,
        open: true
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```